# Fail to read Exec JaCoCo file ANT

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I am trying to generate an XML jacoco report from the generate exec files, but the `ant` is throwing an error that it cannot find an xml file within the jacocoant.jar.  After extracting the files from the jar, the file is there, and has worked in other use cases of this build.xml.

Log from the command `ant -v -debug`

```
52336 $ ant -v -debug
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Detected OS: Mac OS X
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type -> file
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml with URI = file:/Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> product-43
Adding reference: product-43
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> rebuild
Setting ro project property: ant.file.product-43 -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.product-43 -> file
Project base dir set to: /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336
 +Target: 
 +Target: clean
 +Target: merge
 +Target: report
 +Target: rebuild
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Setting project property: result.dir -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/target
Setting project property: result.classes.dir -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes
Setting project property: result.report.dir -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/target/site/jacoco
Setting project property: result.exec.file -> /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco.exec
parsing buildfile jar:file:/Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar!/org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar!/org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/CoverageTask.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.TaskContainer loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.AbstractCoverageTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/AbstractCoverageTask.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Task loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.ant.AbstractCoverageTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Object loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Throwable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.IOException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Collection loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:coverage org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.AgentTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/AgentTask.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.AgentTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:agent org.jacoco.ant.AgentTask
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/ReportTask.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICoverageVisitor
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/analysis/ICoverageVisitor.class
Class org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICoverageVisitor loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICoverageNode
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/analysis/ICoverageNode.class
Class org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICoverageNode loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.report.ISourceFileLocator
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/report/ISourceFileLocator.class
Class org.jacoco.report.ISourceFileLocator loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.analysis.IBundleCoverage
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/analysis/IBundleCoverage.class
Class org.jacoco.core.analysis.IBundleCoverage loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask$SourceFilesElement
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/ReportTask$SourceFilesElement.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.Union loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask$SourceFilesElement loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Iterator loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.List loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.report.IReportVisitor
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/report/IReportVisitor.class
Finding class org.jacoco.report.IReportGroupVisitor
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/report/IReportGroupVisitor.class
Class org.jacoco.report.IReportGroupVisitor loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.report.IReportVisitor loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:report org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/MergeTask.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:merge org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/DumpTask.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecDumpClient
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/tools/ExecDumpClient.class
Class org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecDumpClient loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask$1
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/DumpTask$1.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask$1 loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:dump org.jacoco.ant.DumpTask
Finding class org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/ant/InstrumentTask.class
Class org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Exception loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.OutputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.FileOutputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.runtime.IExecutionDataAccessorGenerator
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/runtime/IExecutionDataAccessorGenerator.class
Class org.jacoco.core.runtime.IExecutionDataAccessorGenerator loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
 +Datatype antlib:org.jacoco.ant:instrument org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> rebuild
Attempting to create object of type org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor
Adding reference: ant.executor
Build sequence for target(s) `rebuild' is [clean, merge, report, rebuild]
Complete build sequence is [clean, merge, report, rebuild, ]

clean:

merge:
[antlib:org.jacoco.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.ResourceCollection loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.File loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecFileLoader
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/tools/ExecFileLoader.class
Class org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecFileLoader loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.ISessionInfoVisitor
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/ISessionInfoVisitor.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.ISessionInfoVisitor loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.IExecutionDataVisitor
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/IExecutionDataVisitor.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.IExecutionDataVisitor loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.BufferedOutputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.InputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.BufferedInputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.io.FileInputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.SessionInfoStore
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/SessionInfoStore.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.SessionInfoStore loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.ArrayList loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataStore
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/ExecutionDataStore.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataStore loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Map loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.Set loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.HashMap loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.util.HashSet loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
fileset: Setup scanner in dir /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336 with patternSet{ includes: [**/*.exec] excludes: [] }
Class org.apache.tools.ant.types.Resource loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.String loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
[jacoco:merge] Loading execution data file /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/10001.exec
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/ExecutionDataReader.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.IncompatibleExecDataVersionException
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/IncompatibleExecDataVersionException.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.IncompatibleExecDataVersionException loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.internal.data.CompactDataInput
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/internal/data/CompactDataInput.class
Class java.io.DataInputStream loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.core.internal.data.CompactDataInput loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.SessionInfo
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/SessionInfo.class
Class java.lang.Comparable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.jacoco.core.data.SessionInfo loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionData
Loaded from /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/jacoco/lib/jacocoant.jar org/jacoco/core/data/ExecutionData.class
Class org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionData loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.IllegalStateException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Long loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml:17: Unable to read /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/10001.exec
    at org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask.load(MergeTask.java:87)
    at org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask.execute(MergeTask.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:853)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:416)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readExecutionData(ExecutionDataReader.java:147)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock(ExecutionDataReader.java:115)
    at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:92)
    at org.jacoco.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:59)
    at org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask.load(MergeTask.java:85)
    ... 18 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to stack trace at the end of your log - this has nothing to do with xml file within the `jacocoant.jar` , `MergeTask` fails:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/build.xml:17:
Unable to read /Users/stephenraghunath/Downloads/gceDist/jacoco-classes/df-coverage/exec/bundle/213864/52336/10001.exec
    at org.jacoco.ant.MergeTask.load(MergeTask.java:87)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    ...
```

And `EOFException` indicates reason of failure - file `10001.exec` is corrupted, see https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/397

Comment: Helpful!  What causes corruption of an exec file?

Comment: @StephenRaghunath depends on how it is generated. As one of examples - JVM process terminated in the middle of writing file to disk. And of course not excluding all the causes of corruption as for any regular file.

P.S. if answer was helpful, then please don't forget to upvote/accept it as a correct one.

Comment: Thanks will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

While @Godin had the right answer for what was revealed by the stack trace. To resolve the issue is the following:

JaCoCo when dumping coverage information is an asynchronous task, and will not be available right away. It may take a few moments for the files to be completely written. Therefore we needed to automate an appropriate timeout before the environment that was creating these exec files would upload them into s3 (10 Seconds).

This was the case for AWS Ec2 instances.